# Need help to pass data from page to dynamic page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a website to showcase products using NextJs. I need to pass data from a page to a dynamic page. All the data is a json array of objects located in a data folder inside the project. I want to list all objects in pages/rolls/index.jsx, and when an objects corresponding "Learn More" Link button is clicked, takes me to a more detailed version of the page. I can't make it work using next/link and useRouter, so here's what I did.
My project structure is:

```
- data
  - rollData.json
- pages
  - rolls
    - [rolldetail].jsx
    - index.jsx
```

```
// rollData.json

[
    {
        "name": "8\" x 0.080\" x 300'",
        "price": 300,
        "product_id": "PL8080300",
        "image": "/8flat.webp",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    },
    {
        "name": "12\" x 0.080\" x 300'",
        "price": 450,
        "product_id": "PL12080300",
        "image": "/12flat.webp",
        "description": "Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra"
    }
]
```

```
// rolls.jsx

import rollsdata from '../../data/rollData.json'

const Rolls = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      {rolls.map((roll) => {
          return (
            <div key={roll.product_id}>

              <h2>{roll.name}</h2>

                <h3>
                  Description
                </h3>
                <p>{`${roll.description.slice(0, 163)}.`}</p>

              <div>
                <span>Price</span>
                <span>{`$${roll.price.toFixed(
                  2
                )}`}</span>
              </div>

                <Link href={`/rolls/${encodeURIComponent(roll.product_id)}`}>
                  <a>click</a>
                </Link>

            </div>
          )
        })}
    </main>
  )
}
```

```
// [rollDetail].js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import rolls from '../../data/rolls.json'

const RollDetail = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const roll = rolls[router.query.rolldetail]

  console.log(roll)
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Roll detail</h2>
      <p>{roll.name}</p>
      <p>{roll.description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RollDetail
```

And it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: roll is undefined
```

I don't understand how to use router to display a specific roll object, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve it please? Should I be using getStaticProps and getStaticRoute?

Answer (score 0):

Actually by default all the routes either they are dynamic or static will be statically pre-rendered during build time of app, unless you use getStaticProps, getInitialProps or getServerSideProps...

But during development all the pages pre-render every time you hit the request to specific url, no matter what you have used...

Now lets back to **actual question**, your dynamic pages will be rendered twice first time you are getting undefined as your url parameters but on second render your url parameters will be availble, so you can simply put checks to check either url parameters are undefined or not...

This is happening due to some reason, checkout this link => [click](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12010)